# how to send data from two forms in a jsp page when u click on submit in one form

Tags: html, jsp

In my project i have a scenario like this if i click submit in a jsp which has two forms i have send data from two forms to destination,how can i do that,Please help me out.

Comment: To be clear: do you want to send two separate HTTP requests in a single click, or do you want to merge the data from both forms and send a single HTTP request?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that you want to send the data from the two forms in the same request, that is not possible.

You would have to copy the data, either from one form to the other, or from both forms into a new form.

You can put hidden fields in a form for the values that you need to copy to it.

Answer (score 0):

The only way i think you can do this is completely bypassing the FORM- mechanism. You could put an `onclick()` javascript event on the submit buttons which calls a javascript function you could call `sendAll()` or something.

In this function you could get all your formfields and values and then send an `XMLHttpRequest` (this is the basic of an ajax request) with all that values in it.

That is indeed complicated but it seems to me that this is the only way it could work.